# One Factory to create entities

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to use one factory to create my entities

```
$this->getServiceManager()->setFactory("order_entity", 
                               new OrderEntityFactory($obj->concept,
                                                      $obj->currency,
                                                      $obj->exchangeRate,
                                                      $obj->cost,
                                                      $obj->percentageOfPayment,
                                                      $obj->accountId,
                                                      $obj->invoiceId,
                                                      $obj->paymentDate,
                                                      $obj->orderStatus,
                                                      $obj->categoryLinkNode));

$orderEntity = $this->getServiceManager()->get("order_entity");
```

I get an order entity, but if I want to put this in a loop and pass values to get other order entities I get an error that I cant re declare, I think that's is obvious I can set a factory name that already was created; how can I create a factory that I can reuse by passing values as a parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather create a factory for some kind of collection storing my entities. For instance,

```
$this->getServiceManager()->setFactory("order_entity_collection",  function($serviceLocator){
    $collection = new \ArrayObject();

    foreach ($myEntities as $entity)
    {
        $collection[] = $entity;
    }

    return $collection;
});
```

You also can add new entities to your collection by doing so,

```
$collection = $serviceLocator->get('order_entity_collection');

foreach ($otherEntities as $entity)
{
    $collection[] = $entity;
}
```

Comment: Hi Next, how would I pass variables to create entities?

Comment: You can put your loop inside the factory logic. However, if I am not mistaking the problem in your case is to retrieve the collection of objects in the factory, so you can iterate it and create the entities. 
In that case, you should get it via service locator. If you could provide more info about how you retrieve the data for your entities I would provide more helpful hint regarding this issue.

Comment: Thanks, What I want to do is create a collection of orders as you mention, but I need to pass variable values (order_id, concept, amount, date) in order to create the orders; this is to hydrate the objects from a data, what I want is pass values tough a parameter and get an order entity as a return. What i see on the factory is that I can just pass the variable once when I create the factory. I hope I am being clearer.. I think what you are suggesting is good to retrieve the values from a data base where I can get the variables from there.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the purpose of the factory provided by ServiceManager library. You use it to create a service, but in your case you want a factory create an entity. You are trying to apply the service factory in wrong context. To achieve what you want, you should create your own entity factory class independently from ServiceManager library. Simply put, entity is NOT a service, so you should not create it by service factory. However, collection of entities can be a service, and thus, can be created by service factory provided by ServiceManager library.

Comment: I got it! great thank you, my only question is way a collection of entities can be a service?

Comment: Anything that gets returned by the factory can be a service, except null. With this in mind, you can create an array of entities in your service factory and retrieve it via service locator. is this your question?

Comment: You say that a service that reruns an entity is not a service, that makes sense because is an entity not a service, but way if the service returns a collection of entities makes it a service.

Comment: By service I meant not an object which provides some kind of service directly, but rather a value, array or object which has an unique purpose in the scope of its context.
For instance, you can have 100 entities in your application, but only a single collection holding these entities. With this in mind, the collection is treated as a service in your application
 since its propose is to provide access to your entities, and it can be of any traversable type (e.g. array, ArrayObject, ArrayIterator).

Comment: OK I got it, thank you! so much for your time explaining this to me.

Comment: @gastoncs If you found my answer as the correct one please mark it accordingly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure to give you a relevant answer for your need

so i would like to bring some clarifications :

declaring a service (for ex as a factory or invokable) and set it as a non shared service will make the service manager giving you a new instance each time you want to get one

also thin means getting a new instance each time will imply that you will need to use setters or hydrators to personalize/populate your instances

be aware that a factory constructor is used to inject a service manager and generally essential dependencies and setters are usually used for optional dependencies and of course updating the instances during the service lifetime